# How do I connect to Hbase using the functionality of Django framework

Tags: django, hbase

We have previously coded an appication to connect to MS Sql through django using django models which worked on MongoDB without change of code.
We would like to do the same with Hbase.Previously answered questions on Stack Overflow are old , So I would like to know if presently there is any way to do this.